# Inserting extra rows within table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am wanting to add a extra 2 rows to my table for each part number which is present. Currently I have something like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| item_number | operation | resource_code |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| abc         |        10 | kit           |
| abc         |        20 | build         |
| abc         |        30 | test          |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

There are hundreds of more items set up like this within the table. I am wanting to add 2 extra lines of records to the table based upon each part number. So once these have been added my data set will look like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| item_number | operation | resource_code |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| abc         | 10        | kit           |
| abc         | 20        | build         |
| abc         | 30        | test          |
| abc         | NULL      | NULL          |
| abc         | NULL      | NULL          |
+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I am wanting these new records to be blank for now and add to them later.

I am using access and looking for the sql to add these new records to the table.

Comment: you want duplicate rows with null values ?

Comment: put your code... what you have done till now

Comment: Yes. These empty values I will be updating later on with new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT item_number, NULL AS operation, NULL AS resource_code 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY item_number
UNION ALL
SELECT item_number, NULL AS operation, NULL AS resource_code 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY item_number
```

Comment: No destination field name in INSERT INTO statement (NULL)

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD oops ;-) Forgot that MS Access was a bit of a pain when it comes to aliasing. The edited answer should do the trick.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'item_number UNION ALL SELECT 'item_number'.

Comment: Sorted. I just took of the union expression and ran the query twice adn it worked.

Comment: So why you would want to insert 2 extra rows, you then probably will get a problem for the update
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999309/updating-records-but-limiting-to-only-one-row-per-duplicate-record sounds familiar to me :s