# Updating records but limiting to only one row per duplicate record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with many item_number records which are duplicates within my table and the other columns within the table for each item_number are blank.

All of the records within the table are under product group of g024. However when I run my query it will update all of my items numbers with this.

What I want it to do is for each item_number only populate resource code, operation and operation description only once and not populating the remianing blank fields for each item_number with the criteria within the query.

I will populate these other black fields with a different update query later on.

```
UPDATE resource1 SET [resource code] ='TOOLASSY', OPERATION = '10',   OPERATION_DESCRIPTION     = 'MOULD TOOL ASSEMBLY'
WHERE [product group]="G024"
```

I did try something like this to make the query only update each item_number only once. I looked into the TOP keyword but not sure if it was on the right line or not.

I need something like the DISTINCT keyword within a sub query for an update query.

```
UPDATE resource1 SET [resource code] ='TOOLASSY', OPERATION = '10', OPERATION_DESCRIPTION = 'MOULD TOOL ASSEMBLY'
WHERE [product group]="G024" AND ITEM_NUMBER IN(SELECT TOP 1 ITEM_NUMBER FROM RESOURCE1)
```

Comment: Can you show us the table definition? If there's a primary key or some other unique field in the table, there's a relatively simple solution, but I need to see the rest of the table.

Comment: There is no primary key at the moment. It was item_number but I took this of to be able to do other tasks. However this can be put back on. There are not other unique fields within the table apart from item_number.

Comment: Then I don't think what you want to do can be done...

Comment: I could always add a new column and assign a distinct value to each row. I.e 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Do that and show me the table definition, and I'll put up the relevant SQL in an answer. :)

Comment: item_number, description, description2, add description, product group,  route num, resource code, OPERATION, OPERATION_DESCRIPTION, SETUP_TIME, RUN_TIME, travel type, travel dwell, WORK CENTRE, SUB_WORK CENTRE, num.            Num is the new field i have added which starts at 1 and each record has its own unique number. I know the table is nor normalized but i am using sql to help create data sheets for imports onto a new system to cut a long story short.

Comment: I am only wanting to update resource code, operation and operation_description as this time.

Comment: Answered as promised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:
`UPDATE resource1 SET [resource code] ='TOOLASSY', OPERATION = '10', OPERATION_DESCRIPTION = 'MOULD TOOL ASSEMBLY'
WHERE [product group]="G024" AND [num] IN (SELECT MinNum FROM (SELECT resource1.[product group], resource1.[item_number], MIN(resource1.[num]) AS MinNum FROM resource1 GROUP BY resource1.[product group], resource1.[item_number])
Q1 WHERE Q1.[product group]=resource1.[product group] AND Q1.[item_number]= resource1.[item_number]);`

Tested in MSAccess 2010.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996862/inserting-extra-rows-within-table